# How to get input value from another input value in one $output PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the value of the input `<input type="text" name="tom" value="0">` to the value of the next input that **data-product_price="'.$row["tom"].'"**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["brand"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["item"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["qty"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["buy"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["sell"].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tom" value="0">'$tom = $_POST["tom"] '</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                       <input type="checkbox" class="select_product" data-product_id="'.$row["id"].'" data-product_name="'.$row["item"].'" data-product_price="'.$row["tom"].'" value="">
                     </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
```

I tried the basic. but every time I failure with syntax errors! So how to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to set the value of input Tom with the value $row['tom']? Or do you want get the value of input after the user change it?

Comment: You miss the dots around $tom = $_POST["tom"] and you can't do this statement inside an var assignment. You have to remove $tom =  before $_POST["tom"]

Comment: here is syntax error, use dot for concatination like : ' ".$tom = $_POST["tom"]." '

Comment: @Stefino76 I want to import the value from the <input type="text" name="tom"> to the checkbox value <input type="checkbox"> like the other parameters I had imported from the sql data table. but that input value doesn't depend on the sql data table. but I want to import value of the text field when I inserted to it a value. but this whole statement is located on the variable that "$output" how to get it?

Comment: You can't do it with php because PHP is a server side language so you can read what the user write inside an input field. You need to use JavaScript. You can use onchange inside the input "Tom" and set the value inserted to the checkbox attriubUte data-product-price by javascript